# Firefox - A vertical tab addon that works with All in One Sidebar

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs, sidebar

I have All in One Sidebar (AISO) installed and am loving it.

now, I was thinking of installing an addon that would display my tabs in the sidebar in a vertical way. Also, this sidebar should integrate seamlessly into AISO.

I tried Vertical tabs, Tree style tabs, Pano etc. but they all take up a separate space adjacent to the AISO to show the tabs. I want an addon that will show the tabs by integrating into AISO.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How would you then drag a tab to the bookmarks?

Comment: As you do normally. Just drag it normally to the bar.

Comment: AISO does not display two sidebars at the same time. I simply use `F4` to expand / collapse AIOS when I need it, and I always leave Tree Style Tabs open adjacent to AIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Pano (unfortunately no more supported) and All In Tabs Helper integrate themselves with All in One Sidebar as you wish.